# Wrong type argument: filenamep error after switching to Emacs v28

Tags: debugging, terminal-emacs

I use emacs in -nw mode on a computer cluster, and was using Emacs v25. I asked my sys admin to install a newer version (27 or higher) because `global-display-line-numbers-mode` was apparently not supported before version 27.

My sys admin then apparently installed Emacs v28.1 through conda

Since then, whenever I start up emacs I get the following error message in `*Messages*`

```
Wrong type argument: filenamep, "/scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/emacs/share/info^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@/" [24 times]
```

The error message does not appear when invoking `-Q nw` or `-q nw`

What does this mean??

The computer cluster OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Do you see that if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q -nw`? If not, do you see it with `emacs -q -nw`? If the answers are no and yes, respectively, then contact the person who installed Emacs and defined the site-wide files. See the Emacs manual, node [Initial Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html).

Comment: Each `^@` is probably a null byte.  My first *guess* would be that there's a corrupted file behind that, because that string value is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: @phils I originally meant when I run `emacs path/to/some/file`. But I just tested just opening emacs without opening a file at the same time, and then it gives me that error as well. When I then open a file via `C-x C-f` it doesn't return any errors. So it is just when opening emacs! I've adjusted the opening post

Comment: @Drew I do not see it if I start with `-Q -nw` and I also do not see it with `-q -nw`. So I'm guessing it must be related with loading `~/.emacs.d/init.el` ?

Comment: Yes. In that case, bisect that file (your init file), to find the culprit. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... of your init file. (With `C-u` it UNcomments the region.)

Comment: @Drew I simply commented all lines in my `init.el` and after that, when starting emacs the error message appears again in `*Messages*`

Comment: What happens if you use a new, fake file as your init file, and it just has some commented (arbitrary-text) lines? Or what happens if you put your commented init file in a different directory (e.g. your `HOME` directory)?

Comment: @Drew, if I move the `init.el` to my `$HOME`, the error message still appears. It also appears when I create a new `init.el` in `~/.emacs.d/` with some arbitrary text lines commented out.

Comment: Note that commenting out your init file won't stop Emacs from initializing the package system and any ELPA packages you have installed (nor from loading default.el and site-start.el libraries, which would typically live elsewhere on the system; but I believe those are both loaded under `-q` so it sounds like those aren't the issue).  You could try renaming your `.emacs.d` directory, and/or setting `package-enable-at-startup` to nil in `early-init.el`

Comment: What @phils said. I didn't think of that (I don't use any packages ;-)). But yes, the idea is to remove any code that *you've* loaded from the mix.

Comment: @phils @drew I have created `.emacs.d/early-init.el` (I didn't already had one) and pasted `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)` into that. After that, starting up emacs did NOT yield the error message. If I commented that line, it would yield the error message again. So it seems the error stems from initializing the package system somehow?

Comment: OP or @phils: Please post the solution you found as an *answer*. (You can select your own answer.) Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: As far as I understand we haven't found the answer yet. Only narrowed it down to that it has something to do with initializing the package system. I would like to be able to start up emacs with packages initialized and without the error message.

Comment: Joran: I'm assuming it's one of your packages, so you now need to figure out which one.  Once you do, try updating it.  Or you could try just updating all of them at the outset (but make backups first).  If updating doesn't fix it, you can always remove it.

Comment: Although given `/scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/emacs/share/info` I do wonder whether it's "any package with an info manual" and perhaps that bad value is being inherited by Emacs from your system and only coming into play if the package system wants to install a new manual for something.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem and managed to fix it by setting `INFOPATH` in my `.bashrc` to the path that's causing the problem, so in OP's case that would be:

`export INFOPATH=/scratch2/software/anaconda/envs/emacs/share/info`

I'm still not sure where Emacs is getting the garbaged version of that path from, but this seems to override it.

Comment: this fixed it for me